# how to get only number from a varchar from a mysql table

Tags: mysql

I need to fetch only numeric digits from the varchar column of a Mysql table. Lets say the value is "€ 899,00" I want to display 899.00 from that column.

Comment: That wouldn't be an easy case for SQL. Use your application formatter to get desired output

Comment: @manwal no as I want to fetch it using SELECT query...I can't edit the existing table schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's the only input and output you're expecting, it might just be best to use replace:

```
SELECT replace(replace(replace('€ 899,00', '€', ''), ',', '.'), ' ', '') as digits
```

Output of the above select is 899.00

The '€ 899,00' could be a column of your table that you're selecting from i.e.:

```
SELECT replace(replace(replace(mycolumn, '€', ''), ',', '.'), ' ', '') as digits 
FROM mytable
```